# Batch script to move files that match another set of files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, move

This would help me a lot of possible.

Example: 
Folder1 has 900 files ending in .zip.
Folder2 has 300 files that match the ones in Folder1 but in .doc

How can I create a batch script to move files from Folder1 to Folder1-sorted that only have a .doc alternative ending up with a folder1-sorted with only 300 .zip files?

My initial guess was doing dir > list.txt and changing the extension of every line and using this list to copy.. but I guess there might be a more clever solution to doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aid of `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `For` loops you could build an indexed array whose values contain just the filenames for your .doc files, using the `~n` variable modifier, then use another for loop on your .zip files to compare against the array with a nested `For /L` loop.

EG:

```
@ECHO OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "your path for parent directory containing folders 1 and 2"

REM build the array using the smaller data set...

PUSHD Folder2
Set "_I=0"
For %%A in (*.doc) Do (
    Set /A _I+=1
    Set "file[!_I!]=%%~nA"
)
POPD
PUSHD Folder1
For %%A in (*.zip) Do (
    For /L %%B in (1,1,!_I!) Do (
        If "!file[%%B]!"=="%%~nA" (
            ECHO(%%A matches !file[%%B]!.doc
REM command for on Match here
        )
    )
)
POPD
```

Comment: In this example what should I move to folder1-sorted?
move %%A C:\somewhere\folder1-sorted?

Comment: if the intent is to move the matching .zip files, use the %%A variable in the line with the on match remark to act on that matching zip file

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much this worked as expected!